# Load JSON data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I would like to know how to load JSON data into an SQL Server 2014 table. 
The 2016 version makes it very easy to do with the built in function, but I can't get the job done without it.
Here are the first 2 lines out of thousands or records I need to import and load.
Thanks

```
{"0":{"SalesOrderNum":"CSVSO67695","OrderDate":"2016-03-05 00:00:00.000","ProductNumber":"WB-H098","Quantity":1},
"1": {"SalesOrderNum":"CSVSO53485","OrderDate":"2015-07-31 00:00:00.000","ProductNumber":"SJ-0194-L","Quantity":10}}
```

Comment: You can load it into a string column.

Comment: how do you parse it so values fall in their respective columns?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ready solutions in internet, and even first result from google search would give you this link:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

There you have quite complex code for functions that will do job for you, with comments, if you would like to understand it ;)

In general if you do not have 2016 or higher version of SQL Server, you need to parse text with JSON looking for its structure elements.

Comment: Google was my first idea :) tried it but it wouldn't work in the end.  I don't have the same data structure.

Comment: What exactly didn't worked? I have used this procedure to process quite big jsons. Only thing I did before was splitting in SSIS on json with many entries, to one record per one item (like those which are numerated by, 0,1 in your file). Also looks like your json have no any further nested items (it is all on same level) and if structure is not changing, actually this can be easily done, just by splitting this string by column names.